# String functions on static strings inside <s:if value = ""> - struts2

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags

I am trying to migrate to Struts 2 and I have the following if scriplet that I have to change to

```
<logic:iterate id="grpItem" collection="<%= impGroupTypeList %>">
    <% if (grpItem.getImpGrpTypCd().trim().equals(impUploadType.trim())){%>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is--OGNL allows (mostly) arbitrary, reasonable method calls inside it. Although that logic shouldn't be happening in the view layer.

Comment: Can you please write an equivalent OGNL or JSTL code which I can use inside <s:if test=" here "> for the above if scriplet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:iterator var="grpItem" value="%{#session.impGroupTypeList}">
                                        <s:if
                                            test='impGrpTypCd.trim().equals(#session.impUploadType.trim())'>
                                            </s:if>
```